# Is there any reference for standard Polymer 1.0 themes?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

It seems that a standard has been built around theming in Polymer 1.0. For example, all paper elements use CSS variables such as `--default-primary-color` and `--primary-background-color`. Ideally all custom material design components should follow this standard, but I'm having trouble finding any reference for it other than the individual elements themselves. Is there any reference out there?

Comment: If it's not here, then it isn't a Polymer standard: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/

Comment: I see your point, though It seems like there should be a reference. If component developers don't use mixins defined by the paper elements, I think it defeats the purpose of "themability".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is the `paper-styles` "component", which all of the paper elements use for their design, typography, colors, etc.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles

It should provide a pretty good example of how to organize a multi-component styling architecture.

Comment: Ah, yeah I think the [default-theme.html](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/master/default-theme.html) file is essentially what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I may have misunderstood your question.  It seems like what you're looking for is a standard method for styling a myriad of existing components which you've imported into an application or site.

Unfortunately this is up to each component author to develop and provide themselves.  In many Polymer tutorials they recommend exporting such things as `--my-component-header` or `--my-component-button` to make this easier, but if they are not provided then you will have to rely on `/deep/`, which I think is getting replaced in upcoming standards updates.